# Will multiprocessing.Process() or multiprocessing.Pool() distribute more evenly across cores?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, python-multithreading

Is there any difference at all (in any way) between creating a pool of processes, or simply looping over a process to create more processes?

What's the difference between this?:

```
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(5)
pool.apply_async(worker)
pool.join()
```

and this?:

```
procs = []
for j in range(5):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(worker)
        p.start()
        procs.append(p)

for p in procs:
    p.join()
```

Will pool be more likely to use more cores/processors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `apply_async` method of a pool will only run the `worker` function once, on an arbitrarily selected process from the pool, so your two code examples won't do exactly the same thing. To really be equivalent, you'd need to call `apply_async` five times.

I think which of the approaches is more appropriate to a give task depends a bit on what you are doing. `multiprocessing.Pool` allows you to do multiple jobs per process, which may make it easier to parallelize your program. For instance, if you have a million items that need individual processing, you can create a pool with a reasonable number of processes (perhaps as many as you have CPU cores) and then pass the list of the million items to `pool.map`. The pool will distribute them to the various worker processes (and collecting up the return values to be returned to the parent process). Launching a million separate processes would be much less practical (it would probably break your OS).

On the other hand, if you have a small number of jobs to do in parallel, and you only need each job done once, it may be perfectly reasonable to use a separate `multiprocessing.Process` for each job, rather than setting up a pool, launching the jobs then tearing down the pool.

Comment: Very interesting, thanks! As a side question, what's the advantage of running a multiprocessor asynchronously, as opposed to in parallel?

If you run your processes asynchronously, why even use multiprocessing?

Comment: @kylex: I'm not sure what you mean by "asynchronously" in your question. If you're referring to the `apply_async` and `map_async` methods of the `Pool` class, what it means is that they don't wait for the other processes to complete their work before letting the parent process move on. Instead, you can provide them with a callback function if you need to know when the job has been completed. There's almost never a good reason to use `pool.apply` instead of `pool.apply_async`, but `pool.map` is often easier to use than `pool.map_async`.